# Separating interpreter command line arguments from script arguments

Tags: command-line, scripting, command-line-arguments

Suppose you have an interpreter that takes command line arguments including the filenames for a script to be run, and optionally further arguments to be passed to the script. The interpreter then needs to figure out which of the given arguments were intended for its own use and which were intended to be passed to the script.

Is there a widely used convention for separating the former from the latter?

Answer (score 0):

[With Bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

```
 --        A -- signals the end of options and disables  further  option
           processing.   Any arguments after the -- are treated as file-
           names and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `CMD` `::` is often used as a dummy argument to indicate recusrsion for instance. Prefixed on a line, it can be used to turn the line into a comment, giving a handy "programmed-skip" facility